# Extracting specifically connected objects from two ArrayLists, combining those related objects and printing from within a subclass

Tags: java, object, arraylist, instance

Based of the information and code below, I want to know how I can have the 'Review' and all the relating 'Replies' specific to that review displayed when I call the printAllReview() in Game.

I have two ArrayLists, one for reviews and one for replies. The ArrayList Review is in the class Content and holds the object . The class Comment has the ArrayList Replies and references itself .

The addReviews() method is in the class Game which extends Content. The addReplies() method is in the class Comment. The printAllReview() method is in the Game class and is the one I want to use to print Reviews and their corresponding replies. The one in Comments is just a tester but the replies do not all print when this is called (I think I know why, I believe it's because how the addReply method is called, but there must be a way around this without changing the call method). I am having a little trouble with the Comment class.

Basically, I don't know how to get my reviews in my review arraylist to match to the replies from my reply arraylist; and then make sure the the replies match the reviews. Also, the review is always added by a specific game object. But the reply is added by the specific comment object that precedes it. I am hoping this acts like a link. Yet they are all Comment objects. Is there such a thing as instance chaining or object inherits object etc...(sounds silly and I can't search it, but you never know?)

I played around with a lot of things but after awhile it gets frustrating. And I've been searching for ages.

Content

```
public abstract class Content {

protected List<Comment> Review = new ArrayList<Comment>();

private String ID;
private String Application_Name;

private int No_of_Downloads = 0;
private double Price = 0;

// constructor to take ID, name and price of app
public Content(String iD, String application_Name, double price) {
    super();
    ID = iD;
    Application_Name = application_Name;
    Price = price;
}

// another constructor for free apps
public Content(String iD, String application_Name) {
    super();
    ID = iD;
    Application_Name = application_Name;
}

public String getApplication_Name() {
    return Application_Name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void Increase_NoD_by1() {
    this.No_of_Downloads += 1;
}

public abstract void addReviews(Comment a);

}
```

Comment - even though I have a print method in this class, I don't want to have it there. Besides it doesn't really function.

```
public class Comment {

protected List<Comment> reply = new ArrayList<Comment>();

protected User user;
protected String usrComment;

public Comment() {
}

public Comment(User usrDetails, String usrComs) {

    this.user = usrDetails;
    this.usrComment = usrComs;
}

public void addReply(Comment r) {

    this.reply.add(r);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.user.getUsr() + '"' + this.usrComment + '"';
}

public void printAllReview() {
    for (Comment a : this.reply) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
}
```

Game - I want to print all the reviews and replies from the the game class because obviously they relate to a specific object. I can print all the reviews but I don't know how to link the reviews to the replies and visa versa. I have been trying a few things but then I just make a mess of my code.

```
public class Game extends Content {

private boolean isMultiPlayer;
private OS o;
private double Price = 0;

public Game(String iD, String application_Name, double price, boolean isMultiPlayer, OS o) {
    super(iD, application_Name, price);
    this.isMultiPlayer = isMultiPlayer;
    this.o = o;
}

public Game(String iD, String application_Name, boolean isMultiPlayer, OS o) {
    super(iD, application_Name);
    this.isMultiPlayer = isMultiPlayer;
    this.o = o;
}

public OS getO() {
    return o;
}

public void printAllReview() {
    for (Comment a : this.Review) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public void addReviews(Comment a) {

    this.Review.add(a);
}
}
```

Main - this is important I think, but I also don't know enough java, but the way the reviews and replies work is a game object will call addReview for the original review. The review object calls the addReply method for the first reply and that first reply calls for the next reply etc... My Logic says that, even though reviews and replies are in different arrayslists, I should be able to match a reply to a review and print them out together.

```
public class Store {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Store admin = new Store();

    // adding new games
    OS os1 = new OS("Android", 4);
    OS os2 = new OS("iOS", 10);
    OS os3 = new OS("Android", 3);
    Game g1 = new Game("g1", "Pokemon", 5, false, os1);
    Game g2 = new Game("g2", "Pokemon", 5, false, os2);
    Game g3 = new Game("g3", "MineCraft", 2, true, os1);

    // adding new users
    User u1 = new User("u1", "Jeremy David", "0412000", 120, os1);
    User u2 = new User("u2", "Bradly Josesp", "0412001", 120, os1);
    User u3 = new User("u3", "James Wilkie", "0412002", 100, os2);
    User u4 = new User("u4", "Will Scobie", "0412003", 50, os3);

    // Review 1
    Comment cm = new Comment(u1, "Loving this Game");
    g1.addReviews(cm);

    // replies for review 1
    Comment cmr1 = new Comment(u2, "I don't have time for it!");
    cm.addReply(cmr1);
    Comment cmr2 = new Comment(u1, "Really??");
    cmr1.addReply(cmr2);
    Comment cmr3 = new Comment(u2, "It's too boring.");
    cmr2.addReply(cmr3);

    // Review 2
    Comment cm2 = new Comment(u3, "Waste of money, so buggy");
    g1.addReviews(cm2);

    // replies for review 2
    Comment cm2r1 = new Comment(u4, "That's becuase games are forever in beta these days.");
    cm2.addReply(cm2r1);
    Comment cm2r2 = new Comment(u4, "That's becuase games are forever in beta these days.");
    cm2r1.addReply(cm2r2);

    // Print out all reviews
    // In reality I would like this method to show all the reviews and the replies
    // for specific reviews.
    g1.printAllReview();

    // this only shows the first reply - I can mix it up by changing it to cmr2,
    // etc..
    // but this is not what I want, I want the replies to be printed with the one
    // method under the reviews
    // I don't know how to link the replies to a specific review
    cm.printAllReview();
}
}
```

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: based of the information and code supplied, I want to how I can have the main review and the following replies displayed when I call the printAllReview() in Game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I understand what You wanna do, but if you want to display somehting like

```
comment1
reply to comment1
reply to comment1
comment2
reply to comment2
```

then the simplest solution is to use recursion. Of course You may wanna add some formatting or more logic to that, but the basic idea is:

create a method in Comment eg.

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println(usrComment);
    for (Comment c : reply) {
        c.display();
    }
}
```

and change the method in Game to

```
public void printAllReview() {
    for (Comment a : this.Review) {
        a.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is sort of what I want to do, however, whenever I try to access the reply ArrayList, nothing prints out.

Comment: u1, name, "something" ---didn't realise I couldn't enter

Comment: Well, as I said, "You may wanna add some formatting or more logic to that". I only presented the basic idea. The display() method I proposed can do more than just print 1 single field. It can do whatever You want, as long as it calls "itself" for all child elements, to ensure all the nodes (because your construct is ultimately a tree) are displayed

Comment: Okay, it just printed with the recursion method...I modified it so now it's back to front

Comment: Yes, recursion is something I've learned a little about, but need to know more. Thanks, I'll have a play a around, and definitely up-vote if I can get it working. Especially because it's simple and elegant IMO.